# XmlRootAttribute placement when deserializing to List

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<Sites>
  <Site>
    <Code>TWTR</Code>
    <Name>twitter.com</Name>
  </Site>
  <Site>
    <Code>FB</Code>
    <Name>facebook.com</Name>
  </Site>
  <Site>
    <Code>SO</Code>
    <Name>stackoverflow.com</Name>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

This is the code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\temp\Sites.xml", FileMode.Open);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Site>));
        var instance = (List<Site>)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Sites")]
public class Site
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The exception I get is: `<Sites xmlns=''> was not expected.`. The reason for this error is usually, when I don't define an XmlRoot for the `XmlSerializer`. But as you can see, I did that by decorating the class `Site` with the `XmlRootAttribute`

To complete my confusion, the following trick works:

Replace

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Site>));
```

with

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Site>), new XmlRootAttribute("Sites"));
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have control over the XML?

Comment: Only limited. The file is generated from MS Dynamics NAV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XmlRoot` attribute you added to `Site` is not used, because you aren't deserializing an object of type `Site`. You are deserializing an object of type `List<Site>` and that's where the serializer looks for the `XmlRoot` attribute.

Your workaround actually is the correct solution. However, if you are performing this deserialization often in your program, be sure to cache the `XmlSerializer` instance, because that specific constructor doesn't internally cache the dynamically generated assemblies - this contrasts with the constructor you normally use.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the memory leak associated with that method.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/532804.aspx

Comment: @ChrisGessler: That article is a mess... But it points out a valid solution to a real problem - if you are able to extract it...

Answer (score 5):

If you have control over the XML, then simply change:

```
<Sites>
```

To

```
<ArrayOfSite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

If you don't have control over the XML, create your own collection and deserialize into that.

```
[XmlRoot("Sites")]
public class Sites : List<Site>
{

}
```

Be careful when using the following constructor:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Site>), new XmlRootAttribute("Sites"));
```

As Microsoft points out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), if you don't cache the instance of the serializer associated with `List<Site>`, you will end up with leaky memory...

> Dynamically Generated Assemblies
>
> To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure
>   dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize
>   specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies.
>   This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)
>
> XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
>
> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the
>   same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a
>   memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one
>   of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must
>   cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following
>   example.