# How to serialize a XML node of repeated elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize some XML into an array of items.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <name>John</name>
    </item>
    <item>
         <name>Jane</name>
    </item>
</items>
```

And my class:

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then deserialize:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item[]), new XmlRootAttribute("items"));
using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    var items = (Item[])xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    var itemCount = items.Length;
}
```

itemCount is 0 (it should be 2).

There is a similar solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544517](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544517/xmlrootattribute-placement-when-deserializing-to-list) but it seem to work only when the XML node names are identical to the class names (mine differ in capitalisation).

What do I need to modify to ensure all the items deserialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root node is `<items>`, so the `Item` class should not have the `XmlRoot` attribute, instead it should use the `XmlType` attribute:

```
[XmlType("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Xml Root "items" is missing

Your class should be:

```
    [XmlRoot("items")]
    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public Item[] Item { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And the code to deserialize:

```
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items), new XmlRootAttribute("items"));
        using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            var items = (Items)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            var itemCount = items.Item.Length;
        }
```

Comment: I have managated to get your solution to work previously. Unfortunately I need the object return to be a array/list/collection etc. I want to be able to have just items.Length

Comment: I m not sure to undestand, in my reply you will have a List/Array of "Name" : foreach (var item in items.Item) { Response.Write(item.Name); } will return ==> John, Jane

Comment: Let me try and clarify. I want to be able to write the following statement: foreach(var item in items). Similar to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544517