# Error while trying to read XML values in Code

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a code to read records from XML file. XML file is:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfFeedbackData")]
public class FeedbackData
{ 
    public string Criteria { get; set; }
     
    public int Excellent { get; set; }
     
    public int Good { get; set; }
     
    public int Average { get; set; }
     
    public int Dissatisfied { get; set; }
}
```

The code to read records is:

```
  private void EnterFeedback_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      lstFD = (List<FeedbackData>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
  }
```

Everytime I execute the code, I am getting error in  `lstFD = (List<FeedbackData>)xs.Deserialize(fs);`:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'
 InvalidOperationException: <ArrayOfFeedbackData xmlns=''> was not expected."
```

The sample XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfFeedbackData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<FeedbackData>
    <Criteria>Food Quality</Criteria>
    <Excellent>0</Excellent>
    <Good>0</Good>
    <Average>0</Average>
    <Dissatisfied>0</Dissatisfied>
</FeedbackData>
<FeedbackData>
    <Criteria>Staff Friendliness</Criteria>
    <Excellent>0</Excellent>
    <Good>0</Good>
    <Average>0</Average>
    <Dissatisfied>0</Dissatisfied>
</FeedbackData>
<FeedbackData>
<Criteria>Cleanliness</Criteria>
<Excellent>0</Excellent>
    <Good>0</Good>
    <Average>0</Average>
    <Dissatisfied>0</Dissatisfied>
</FeedbackData>
<FeedbackData>
    <Criteria>Order Accuracy</Criteria>
    <Excellent>0</Excellent>
    <Good>0</Good>
    <Average>0</Average>
    <Dissatisfied>0</Dissatisfied>
</FeedbackData>
```

This is the XMLFile that I have.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Would you be so kind and add an example xml?

Comment: I have added an example XML file..

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544517/xmlrootattribute-placement-when-deserializing-to-list Seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Show how you create a serializer. I bet you do: `new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeedbackData))`. And it should be like this: `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<FeedbackData>))`

Comment: Note: you can remove the `XmlRootAttribute` from your class - you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfFeedbackData));
            ArrayOfFeedbackData arrayOFeedbackData = (ArrayOfFeedbackData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public class ArrayOfFeedbackData
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<FeedbackData> FeedbackData { get; set; }
    }
    public class FeedbackData
    {
        public string Criteria { get; set; }

        public int Excellent { get; set; }

        public int Good { get; set; }

        public int Average { get; set; }

        public int Dissatisfied { get; set; }
    }
}
```